# Google App Engine: fail to load a BigQuery php page while deploying it with other php pages

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am working on a Google APP Engine based project now.

I just finished a php page named "heroes.php" using BigQuery and it was **working** when I deployed it individually.

However when I re-deployed my "index.php" as my project home page and set a link to "heroes.php":

```
 function recruitHero(num) {
    window.location.href = "heroes.php";    
}
```

It shows me:

`This page isn’t working and xxxx.appspot.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`.

This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: xxxx
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

[image]

I don't know why "heroes.php" stops working when I deployed "index.php" and "heroes.php" together, again when deployed "heroes.php"by itself, its working!

Thank you for your time to read my post!